# Object and fluid displacement

Tags: fluid-statics

When an object is located inside a fluid, how it displaces the volume of the fluid? what is the cause of it
?

Comment: Nothing mysterious. The object and fluid cannot both occupy the same space. The object occupies space that could have been occupied by fluid or used to be occupied by fluid.

Comment: true that but physically speaking how the object is displacing the fluid? and where this fluid will go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a glass of water, and drop a pebble into it. The pebble displaces the fluid, like you've said. Analogically, this would be similar to a person pushing around in a crowded room, to make space for themselves. (because two humans can't technically be in the same place at the same time.) The pebble displaces the water around it, because a pebble and water can't occupy the same spacial position at the same time. If you observe, you'll notice that the water level rises. (This is where the displaced fluid "goes".)

Comment: we can say that the molecules of the fluid are pushed away by the object and are deflected to another place right?

Comment: Exactly, you can.